# mySQL syntax while creating a new procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, syntax

I can't seem to figure out what is syntax error here. According to my text book it should be correct but for some reason MySQL doesn't like it. 
Here is the code:

...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test
(
    products_qty    INT
)
BEGIN
    SET products_qty = COUNT(product_id)
IF products_qty >= 7 THEN
    SELECT 'The number of products is greater than or equal to 7';
ELSEIF products_qty < 7 THEN
    SELECT 'The number of products is less than7';
END IF;
```

...

Comment: we need more than "MySQL doesn't like it." What does that mean? are you getting an error message? if so, what is the message? if you are not getting an error message, what makes you think that the code doesn't work as it should?

Comment: See about delimiters

Comment: Your textbook is of dubious quality :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@twicelost I was able to get the procedure to work. Here is a summary of the things I had to change to get it to work:

1. you were missing `DELIMITER //` at the beginning of the procedure
2. you were referring to `COUNT(product_id)` without specifying the rest of the query or the table you were wanting to get the value from
3. you didn't declare the variable `products_qty`. you listed it as a value that was passed in to the procedure which is not what you should do if you are going to set the value of the variable inside the procedure
4. you were missing the `END // DELIMITER ;` at the end of the procedure

Based on what you posted, this is what I believe you want your procedure to look like:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE test ()
BEGIN
    DECLARE products_qty INT;
    SELECT COUNT(product_id) INTO products_qty FROM some_table;
    IF products_qty >= 7 THEN
        SELECT 'The number of products is greater than or equal to 7';
    ELSEIF products_qty < 7 THEN
        SELECT 'The number of products is less than 7';
    END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

[Here is the procedure mocked up in db-fiddle;](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/whRiK8Mw9u14CcwqTqBvhL/4)

If this isn't what you want your procedure to do, please post more details on what is wrong with your procedure and what you want it to do, we'll help you as best we can.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Delimiter is a client specific command, not a mysql one, not all clients need it. A parameter can be used to return value, not just to provide input. The OP may need a fujction, not a procedure. In short: we have no clue want the OP wants to do,  we have no idea what the error was, so this answer is unfortunately just a guess.